# Dagger2, ViewModelProvider.Factory: <some-type> uses more than one @MapKey annotation type

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am developing a library which defines some Fragments. The library now needs to be integrated in an already existing app.

Both projects use Dagger2 & Dagger2 Android and I can modify the sources of both the library & the app. They both use MVVM & use [this](https://proandroiddev.com/viewmodel-with-dagger2-architecture-components-2e06f06c9455) way of injecting ViewModel instances their Fragments.

In the library I have:

**Binding Module:**

```
@Module
abstract class LibViewModelBindingModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindLibViewModelFactory(factory: LibraryViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

**LibraryViewModelFactory**

```
class LibraryViewModelFactory
@Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}
```

The app has basically carbon copies of the classes above:

**App Binding Module:**

```
@Module
abstract class AppViewModelBindingModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindAppViewModelFactory(factory: AppViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

**AppViewModelFactory**

```
class AppViewModelFactory
@Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}
```

After integrating the library into the app (as an `.aar`), and after adding the Dagger2 modules defined in the library to the app's Dagger2 dependency graph, when trying to build, Dagger stops the build due to the following error:

```
e: <long-path>/MainAppComponent.java:37: error: [Dagger/MapKeys] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> uses more than one @MapKey annotation type
public interface MainAppComponent {
                 ^
```

I know I could theoretically delete `AppViewModelFactory` & just use `LibraryViewModelFactory` in the app as well, but it's more work & feels like a workaround. I also don't want to do this for all the apps I'll be integrating my library into.

Among others, I also tried using a qualifier for the map received by `LibraryViewModelFactory`, but that didn't help:

```
class LibraryViewModelFactory
@Inject constructor(@LibraryViewModelsMap private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}
```

Any ideas? Feels like I'm missing something very obvious

Comment: The error would suggest that you use 2 different `@ViewModelKey` (or whatever it is called that you use for your `@BindsInto` declarations) annotations

Comment: Right...I am using two of them: one declared in the library, and another one for the app. So I assume the most straightforward way would be use in the app the `@ViewModelKey` declared in the library. Can I bypass this, and actually keep having 2 separate `@ViewModelKey` for the same data type?

Comment: I think this `AppViewModelFactory` stuff is generally a mistake, and people should be using the approach outlined in https://youtu.be/9fn5s8_CYJI?t=1720

Comment: Yeah, in my previous projects I was using a simplified version of the method in the video before. But now, I used this this method of injecting the factory in the library as all the projects that are supposed to consume the library are using it, I didn't see any obvious flaws with it and I wanted to ensure consistency across projects. But given the all headaches, might as well go with the method in the video in the library itself. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @cjurjiu did you resolve this? i'm facing the same problem, injecting libs into app, kindly help... thanks...